# GetMapping can not recognize Sharp Sign

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to add # in my GetMapping?
Code `@GetMapping("/C")` and `@GetMapping("/C#")` is equals for me(

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you cannot.

The character "#" is excluded because it is used to delimit a URI from a fragment identifier. The percent character "%" is excluded because it is used for the encoding of escaped characters. In other words, the "#" and "%" are reserved characters that must be used in a specific context.

[You can read more on the URL's RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2).